# Webhook Notifications Only Append "event" For Embedded Signing

Tags: docusignapi

Our application implements both the local/embedded signing and the non-embedded emailed signing, using Docusign's own "eSign client" SDK. I always include envelope- and recipient-level event notifications and rely on the webhooks to tell me what happened. The "embedded" version always appends something like "&event=cancel" to the callback URL I set in the envelope definition, but the remote version never does; it only sends back the exact callback URL I sent *to* it. There is, therefore, no way at all to tell what the signer did if the document was emailed to them to be signed.

How do I make it append the "event" to the query string for remote signing like it does for local?

Comment: I believe this is by design, though we can let others chime in. For the remote/email signing scenario, you can consider looking at the signing resource branding -> landing pages. The browser can re-direct to the URL's you list there in these instances.

Comment: I would do that, but you have to include the hostname in those. Our callback host isn't going to be a constant; several different websites will be using it in production (we do SaaS). So webhooks (which are dynamic and use HTTP_HOST to set the hostname) are really my only option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing apples and oranges:

1. When you use the embedded signing feature, you supply a url. When the recipient has completed their action, your url is *re-directed to* with an `event` query parameter. This mechanism is **not** webhooks or `eventNotification`. Rather, it enables your app to regain control of the signer's browser after they've completed their embedded session with DocuSign.
2. `eventNotification` creates a webhook (Connect) subscription for just that envelope. When an event occurs, your app receives a *POST* request from DocuSign. That request's body includes an XML file with lots of information on the new status of the envelope.
3. You can include an `eventNotification` object when you're doing embedded signing. In this case, your app would be re-directed to after the embedded session completes. A bit later you'll receive a POST from the eventNotification (Connect webhook) system

Comment: Silly me, expecting consistency. I just didn't want to have to parse all that XML just to get one Status out of it. But why does the embedded signing always send exactly this if it isn't a webhook?

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

Anyway, guess I'll just waste the CPU cycles parsing XML because they can't append one variable to the callback URL. Makes no sense at all to me.